# ksh: for loop to loop through files in a particular directory

Tags: shell-script, filenames, ksh

```
schema_dir=schema_app
for SCHEMA_CHANGE in $schema_dir/*
do
```

so my pwd is `/A/B/C/scripts`
within which I have subdirectories (`schema_app`, `schema_data`, etc).
I want a for loop to run through the files in each directory, depending upon the parameter I pass to the script initially.

What mistake am I doing here ?
Because, when I echo `SCHEMA_CHANGE` (the file name), it is showing like this `schema_app/filename`.
how can I get only the `filename` here ?

Comment: `printf %s\\n "${SCHEMA_CHANGE#*_*/}"`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing anything wrong. `schema_app/filename` is the correct path to the file. It's what you need to pass to a command (or a redirection) to work on the file. Using `filename` alone wouldn't work: how would the command know in what directory the file is?

If for some reason you need the filename without its directory part, you can use

```
"${SCHEMA_CHANGE##*/}"
```

This takes the value of the variable `SCHEMA_CHANGE` and removes the part up to and including the last `/` (or leaves the value unchanged if there's no `/`), so you get the filename without its directory part.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. This works as expected... Curious what does the '##*/' mean though ?

Comment: @MRKR takes the value of the variable `SCHEMA_CHANGE` and removes the part up to and including the last `/` (removes the longest prefix matching `*/`).